# Recursive Partition Sort is Acting Ineffecient

Tags: java, sorting, quicksort

I have written a recursive method for a partition sort that sorts the array however when I use an array of more than 10-20 elements the program takes a really long time to complete (On my computer a bubble sort of a 100,000 int array will take about 15-20 seconds but with an array of only 30 ints my partition sort is taking around 45 seconds to be sorted.

Here is the code.

```
public static int[] partitionSortRecursive(int[] array, int beginning, int end)
{
    if (end < beginning)
        return array;

    int pivot = (array[beginning] + array[end]) / 2;
    int firstUnknown = beginning;
    int lastS1 = beginning - 1;
    int firstS3 = end + 1;


    while (firstUnknown < firstS3)
    {
        if (array[firstUnknown] == pivot)
        {
            firstUnknown++;
        }
        else if (array[firstUnknown] > pivot)
        {
            firstS3--;
            int temp = array[firstUnknown];
            array[firstUnknown] = array[firstS3];
            array[firstS3] = temp;
        }
        else
        {
            lastS1++;
            int temp = array[firstUnknown];
            array[firstUnknown] = array[lastS1];
            array[lastS1] = temp;
            firstUnknown++;
        }

    }

    partitionSortRecursive(array, 0, lastS1);
    partitionSortRecursive(array, firstS3, end);

    return array;
}
```

Comment: you can post this at code review.

Comment: What is code review?

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not use the correct pivot element. You calculate the average of the left and right value but you have to take a sample value from the sub array to partition instead.

You may take the rightmost, the center or any other element. So your first line of codes should look like this

```
int pivot = array[(beginning + end) / 2];
// or
int pivot = array[end];
```

You could also take any other element (e.g. random)

EDIT: This does not solve the performance issue.

To my understanding, quick sort will divide an array into two sub arrays A and B where all elements in A are smaller than any element in B and then perform the same operation onto the two sub arrays.

So the basic call structure should be like this

```
void DoSort (array, i, j)
{
  pivot = Partition (array, i, j)
  DoSort (array, i,pivot)
  DoSort (array, pivot + 1, j)
}
```

Put your implementation is basically

```
void DoSort (array, i, j)
{
  pivot = Partition (array, i, j)
  DoSort (array, 0, pivot)     // <<<<<< notice the '0' instead of 'i'
  DoSort (array, pivot + 1, j)
}
```

So you always start from the very beginning of the original array which will most likely take a while

Comment: This shouldn't effect how long the partition takes as at the end of the day the number is still just a random number I chose to divide the add the numbers in the first and last index in case the first or last number were the highest or lowest number in the array which would skew the partition, but changing that wouldnt make the array sort quicker since each "sub array" is creating a new pivot number based on the values in its array.

Comment: Hmm.. You are right. I will edit the answer. Please note that this includes another error.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of direct recoursive call like this

```
partitionSortRecursive(array, 0, lastS1);
partitionSortRecursive(array, firstS3, end);
```

Organize internal stack where you can save index pairs. While the stack is not empty get the next pair from the stack. In the end of function don't call the same function but put in the stack 2 pairs `(0, lastS1)` and `(firstS3, end)`

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm simply misunderstanding what you are saying but wouldn't that be an iterative solution rather than a recursive one?

Comment: Recursive and iterative quicksort solutions usually differ in about +/- 10%. I've tested this using Delphi quite a long time ago and could imagine that it is similar in Java.

However, what you suggest will propably boost the solution by another 10-20% but I doubt that it solves the performance issue which has a magnitude of 100-1000

Comment: In fact it's the same recursion but with your own stack. In your case  lot of time is spent on function call (placing in the internal stack on entering function and restoring)

Comment: If you use 'roll out' it does not include a stack but performs sorting of the left sub array in another outer loop.